# Power Consumption of a sensor

Tags: power, sensor

I am working on assignment in which I have a task  for selecting a sensor from various ,for that I am considering battery life as an criteria to decide, so calculating the time for which that sensor works on 2500mAh battery.

I have calculated in this way, taking reference from this [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/469115/how-to-calculate-average-power-consumption-in-mah)

For Ultrasonic sensor :

- Opeartional current -- 0.015A
- Standby current --14*10^-6
- Operational duration --0.01 sec
- Frequency -- 600 times/hr
- On time = 6 sec
- Off Time = 3594 sec

Life of battery = 0.015 * 6+ 3594 * 14*10^-6 = 0.09+0.050316 = 0.140 Amp

--> (2500mAh/0.140A) = 28 hr //Some thing wrong here dont know the what exact come here

Here Opeartional current and standby current are self explanatory.Operational duration is the time for which the senor on. Frequency is how many times a sensor go in to on state.

Average current = what I have done is -- operational current * Time for which it on + Standby current * Time for which it if off

Life = Total batter power/Avg Current

Is I am doing it correctly ? I am very confused with the sleep current, is it for an hr or for all time.
Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

EDIT1: Influenced by Polynomial comment, I have made all the units normalized basically time in seconds and current is in mA.
Second: Influenced by user25371 comment, Actually I missed to add, for the instance please ignore consumption by micro-controller.Regardless it is obvious it will connect using micro-controller.

Third : Please suggest Theoretical calculation, I am very aware that practically these things are going to very differ.

Comment: How is the sensor connected to the battery?

Comment: And if you think about this for longer than 10 seconds, you will notice that a sensor which uses 15mA when it's on, and 0.014mA when it's off, can't possibly use 140mA on average.

Comment: I think your maths would be clearer if you normalised your numbers to base SI units like seconds and amps, rather than mixing milliseconds, milliamps, microamps, etc. - it'll probably help you get a clearer picture about the magnitude of these things. The magnitude will help you get a better picture of the effect of each current on battery life in the given timeframe.

Comment: How did you get current consumption bigger then operational current?

Comment: user25371 and polynomial, I have edited the question as per your suggestion. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @user263983, well you raised a valid point, that clearly  means I am doing some thing wrong surely.I need help here.

Comment: You are also confusing "energy" and "power". If you divide power by average current you get average **voltage**, not time. You need to divide total energy by average power to get time.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson well I am really  confused :(  . What will be the total energy for that case ?

Comment: The total energy is the energy that you can get from the battery before it becomes unusable in your application.

Comment: @user263983 Edited now.

Comment: Cycle is 3600s,  which is one hour. How can it be 600 times/hour?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, How can I calculate the total energy that i can get from 2500 mAh for my use case, please elaborate, how this will going to affect my calculation.

Answer (score 1):

The formula to get average current consumption over one ON/OFF cycle is:

$$I_{avg} = \frac{I_{ON} \times t_{ON} + I_{OFF} \times t_{OFF}}{t_{cycle}}$$

Your error is that you did not normalize the average current calculation by the complete cycle time.

Then it is straightforward to get expected battery life as you did.

Comment: Thanks for ans, this means 140/3600 = 0.038mA then battery life is : ~64285 hr